# Getting ???? as response for Indian regional languages in java web application

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, hibernate

I'm working on the java web application using spring and hibernate. For normal english, I'm getting proper response and my encoding is utf-8.
There is no problem for other languages as well. There is specific instance for which I'm facing issue. 
When I enter this word 'క్రియేటివ్ వర్చ్యువ' , it gets saved in db and there is no issue in fetching as well.

While fetching this word from db using the following request, I'm getting ????:

Following is the code snippet:

```
var data = { domainId: domainId };
$.post('getNameById.html', data, function(name) {
    alert('name = '+name);
});

@RequestMapping(value = "/getNameById.html")
public @ResponseBody String getNameById(@RequestParam Integer domainId, HttpSession session)
{
    // make db call and fetch the domain object based on domainId;
    // get the name form domain object and then return that name;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified the value isn't corrupted in the database? I.e. if you log it after you've retrieved from a database, does it show correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's verified. Data isn't corrupted in db.

Comment: One thing special about this alphabet is that most of the letters seem to be combined characters. I'd recommend plugging in the string directly into the template and/or into the controller to see which layer might be garbling your characters.

Comment: Binding it directly to template works but it didn't work when i try to fetch it jquery post individually.